# Sorting union queries in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am making a search feature for a Job listing website. For that I need to first show the listings with matching titles and then the job listings with matching description. Here is the query, I am using right now:

Example:

```
(SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE title LIKE '%java%developer%') 
UNION DISTINCT 
(SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE description LIKE '%java%developer%')
```

However, I also need to sort the results by the timestamp so as to show the latest results first. Like it should give the results with matching titles sorted by timestamp and then the listings with matching description sorted by timestamp.

Comment: Are you saying *all* the Title matches should precede *all* the Description matches? Because recent Description matches are probably more valuable than old Title matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would probably write the query similar to:

```
  select *, ((title like '%…%')*2 + (description like '%…%')) as rank
    from jobs
   where title like '%…%'
      or description like '%…%'
order by rank desc, time desc
```

this way, rows where both title and description match will appear first, then title-matches, then description-matches. i haven't tested it, but usually mysql does a good job converting bool to int (true: 1, false: 0)

Answer (score 3):

Try this, replace `timestamp` by the name of your timestamp column

```
(SELECT *, 1 as unionsorting FROM `jobs` WHERE title LIKE '%java%developer%' ORDER BY timestamp desc)
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT *, 2 as unionsorting FROM `jobs` WHERE description LIKE '%java%developer%' ORDER BY timestamp desc)
ORDER BY unionsorting
```

But doing 2 queries is probably faster (this has to be tested)

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE title LIKE '%java%developer%' ORDER BY timestamp desc
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE description LIKE '%java%developer%' ORDER BY timestamp desc
```

Comment: woulnd't the timestamp column sort would take precedence over the title > description sort?

Comment: @potatopeelings Yes i misread the question and updated my answer ! Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: This works nicely, but you need to change `1 as unionsorting, *` to `*, 1 as unionsorting`.

Comment: @mike: why? order is irrelevant

Comment: @knittl: The use of an unqualified `*` can produce a parsing error. Placing the `*` first, or using a table reference (`tbl.*`) solves the problem. This may only affect some MySQL versions, and it definitely affects mine (5.0.51a-24+lenny3). See [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), look for "Use of an unqualified".

Comment: @mike: never mattered for my cases, but i don't have a mysql installation to test right now

Comment: @knittl: It's only a problem when used with other items in the select list.

Comment: This will give some redundant results, since listings having the keywords both in the title and the description will be returned twice. Adding 1 or 2 will make the distinct irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** to fix...

This is a little clunky, but some variation on it will work:

```
SELECT title, description, timestamp_column, min(rank) from 
(
    (SELECT *, 1 as rank FROM `jobs` WHERE title LIKE '%java%developer%') 
    UNION
    (SELECT *, 2 as rank FROM `jobs` WHERE description LIKE '%java%developer%')
) x
GROUP BY title, description, timestamp_column 
ORDER BY min(rank), timestamp_column DESC
```

This uses the `GROUP BY` clause in place of `DISTINCT`

Comment: the timestamp column sort would take precedence over the title > description sort, right?

Comment: @potatopeelings: Fixed, I think.

Comment: This will give some redundant results, since listings having the keywords both in the title and the description will be returned twice. Adding 1 or 2 will make the distinct irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `jobs` 
WHERE (title LIKE '%java%developer%' OR description LIKE '%java%developer%')
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN title LIKE '%java%developer%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), timestamp_col DESC
```

Comment: isn't an END required for the CASE?

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM `jobs` A WHERE title LIKE '%java%developer%' ORDER BY A.colDateTime desc) 
UNION DISTINCT 
(SELECT * FROM `jobs` B WHERE description LIKE '%java%developer%' ORDER BY B.colDateTime desc)
```

Comment: um... would this be consistent? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html > ...However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  See [UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).  Look for 'use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order'.

Comment: As said by others, this doesn't works since the order is changed when we do the Union