# ordering problem with CSV file export from MySQL with headings

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I want to export from MYsql to csv with ordered by two columns, i found this tutorial: http://homepage.mac.com/kelleherk/iblog/C711669388/E20060511141025/index.html
But its not working for me properly. If I use the statement without parenthesis, it does the ordering, but using my header as a data row. But if I use the parenthesis, it does not do any oredring at all. What can be the problem?
My query is:

```
SELECT 'type' ,'brand' ,'timecenter_hu' ,'karorauzlet_hu' ,'karorauzlet_hu_diff',
'karorauzlet_hu_link', 
UNION (SELECT type, brand, timecenter_hu, karorauzlet_hu,
karorauzlet_hu_diff, karorauzlet_hu_link 
INTO OUTFILE 'c://result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES 
TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM 
result ORDER BY brand);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT UNION and ORDER BY in mysql.. how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175312/select-union-and-order-by-in-mysql-how-to)

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need an extra query to do the export to CSV:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 'type' ,'brand' ,'timecenter_hu' ,'karorauzlet_hu' ,'karorauzlet_hu_diff' ,'karorauzlet_hu_link'
     UNION 
    (SELECT type, brand, timecenter_hu, karorauzlet_hu, karorauzlet_hu_diff, karorauzlet_hu_link 
        FROM result
        ORDER BY brand)) AS tmp
INTO OUTFILE 'c://result.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: no, its not working. It does the ordering, but my header is not in the first row. It is included in the ordering as data.

Comment: Sorry, you have to put the second query in the union in parenthesis, to make sure the ORDER BY only applies to that part. I updated my answer.

Comment: it still not working for me. if i run your updated query, it does not do the ordering.

Comment: Your right, this isn't as straightforward as I imagined, please look check out the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175312/select-union-and-order-by-in-mysql-how-to you will need some sort of construction like that one in the inner query....

Comment: The 2nd answer in the above linked issue works for me. This question might be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3175312/880188.